# order by HIGHVALUE on user_tab_partitions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to run below query in my PL/SQL block

```
SELECT partition_name, high_value FROM user_tab_partitions WHERE table_name = 'BRD_JOB_DETAILS_TMP' order by high_value;
```

I am getting the error message : `ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype`

I need to process table partitions in order of `high_value`to get rid the below issue :

```
ORA-14074: partition bound must collate higher than that of the last partition
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the numeric column `partition_position` instead for your order.

```
SELECT partition_name, high_value FROM user_tab_partitions WHERE table_name = 'BRD_JOB_DETAILS_TMP' order by partition_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of list partitioning partition number may not be aligned with actual value order. But as long as`LONG` columns has [a lot of restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F) in SQL, the common way to deal with them is to use `dbms_xmlgen.getxml[type]` to serialize `long` value into text and then retrieve it as `varchar2`.

Below is an example:

> ```
> create table t (
>   id date
> )
> partition by list(id) (
>   partition p20200101 values (date '2020-01-01'),
>   partition p20200601 values (date '2020-06-01'),
>   partition p20200301 values (date '2020-03-01')
> )
> ```

> ```
> with
> /*In case of date column high_value contains an expression,
> not the value itself.
> So evaluation is required.*/
>
> function f_evaluate_val (p_val varchar2)
>   return date
> /*Evaluates high_value as SQL expression*/
> as
>   l_res date;
> begin
>   execute immediate
>     'select ' || p_val || ' from dual'
>     into l_res;
>   return l_res;
> end;
>
> a as (
>   /*wrap with xmltype as long as LONG columns
>   are not accessible for functions in SQL*/
>   select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(q'{
>     select
>       table_name,
>       partition_name,
>       high_value
>     from user_tab_partitions
>     where table_name = 'T'
>   }') as x
>   from dual
> )
>
> select
>   t.table_name,
>   t.partition_name,
>   f_evaluate_val(t.high_value) as hv
> from a
>   cross join xmltable(
>     '//ROWSET/ROW'
>     passing a.x
>     columns
>       table_name varchar2(30),
>       partition_name varchar2(30),
>       high_value varchar2(4000)
>   ) t
> order by hv desc
> ```
>
> ```
> TABLE_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | HV       
> :--------- | :------------- | :--------
> T          | P20200601      | 01-JUN-20
> T          | P20200301      | 01-MAR-20
> T          | P20200101      | 01-JAN-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a98afab65242f93f332bca7be1c60bc4)*